# How to pass an intent to other activities while keeping the drawer, in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm currently making use of the template (with the navigation drawer) at [this site](http://androidshenanigans.blogspot.sg/2015/03/material-design-template.html). However, like with most navigational drawers, fragments are used to keep the drawer items.

I would like to be able to go from activity > nav drawer > fragment > to another activity because I want to include a google map in that activity.

This activity, for convenience sake, will be called `add_route_activity.xml`. The fragment I want to pass it *from* is `my_routes_fragment.xml` My problem is that I want `add_route_activity.xml` to also have the navigational drawer.

My main activity is called `activity_main.xml`. Is there any way I can achieve what I want? I am currently using Android Studio.

Anyway, what I have tried is to create another activity (`add_route_activity.xml`) with the Material Design Template fragment but my app crashes. Below are some of my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.my.app;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);
        // populate the navigation drawer
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUserData("John Doe", "johndoe@doe.com", Bit

        mapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.avatar));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Toast.makeText(this, "Menu item selected -> " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new ParkFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new MyGalleryFragment();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new NavigationFragment();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new MyEventsFragment();
                break;
            case 6:
                fragment = new MyActivitiesFragment();
                break;
            case 7:
                fragment = new MyRoutesFragment();
                break;
            case 8:
                fragment = new PlannerFragment();
                break;
            case 9:
                fragment = new SignInFragment();
                break;
            case 10:
                fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();

        }
        else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }    
    }    

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen())
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.closeDrawer();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**MyRoutesFragment.java**

```
package com.my.app;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyRoutesFragment extends Fragment {

    public MyRoutesFragment() {}

    Context context;
    Button btnAddRoute;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_routes, container, false);

        btnAddRoute = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddRoute);
        btnAddRoute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddRouteActivity.class);
                //startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Specifically, the app crashes when I try to run `AddRouteActivity` using the template (with the nav drawer). Essentially what I was trying to do is to create a new nav drawer at `AddRouteActivity` and populate it with the same items, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What we did is that we have a custom view that is bound to the left navigation drawer within the drawer layout.

```
public class LeftNavigationDrawerView
        extends LinearLayout {
    public static final String TAG = LeftNavigationDrawerView.class.getSimpleName();

    @Inject
    LeftNavigationDrawerPresenter leftNavigationDrawerPresenter;

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    public LeftNavigationDrawerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public LeftNavigationDrawerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    @TargetApi(11)
    public LeftNavigationDrawerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @TargetApi(21)
    public LeftNavigationDrawerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.dashboard_drawer_tv_programs_ll)
    public void onClickTvProgramsDrawerBtn() {
        leftNavigationDrawerPresenter.startTVPrograms();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.dashboard_drawer_settings_ll)
    public void onClickSettingsDrawerBtn() {
        leftNavigationDrawerPresenter.startSettings();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        this.drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getParent();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        Injector.INSTANCE.getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        ButterKnife.unbind(this);
    }
}
```

And its XML layout

```
<com.acme.LeftNavigationDrawerView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_left"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/left_navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_drawer_tv_programs_ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_tv_programs" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/tv_show" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_drawer_settings_ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/settings" />

    </LinearLayout>

</com.acme.LeftNavigationDrawerView>
```

Because then you can include it in your activities' XML where you need it

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/dashboard_activity_drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/epg_dashboard_bg">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <include layout="@layout/layout_dashboard_content" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <include layout="@layout/layout_navigation_drawer_left"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

If you don't want to use magic libraries that make `@Inject` work, then refer to [the first half of this guide "The Android Way" on spring.io](https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/26/clean-code-in-android-applications)